# Swip from one view to the next view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an app with two views and ViewControllers. How can I let the user swip from one view to the next view like in the homescreen or the weatherapp.

I know that there is a page control in the Interface Builder, but it is just an Indicator on what page the user is.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the PageControl.xcodeproj from Apple's iPhone sample code. It provides a template for doing exactly what you want.

The actual paging is done using a UIScrollView in page mode with horizontal scrolling (which is what causes the scrolling to "snap" to a page boundary).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - it even turns the scroll indicators off, as they look kind 0f ugly in this scenario..