# Drag & sweep with Cocoa on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, drag, panels

I'm about to start a new iPhone app that requires a certain functionality but I'm not sure if it's doable. I'm willing to research but first I just wanted to know if I should at least consider it or not.

I haven't seen this in an app before (which is my main concern, even though I haven't seen too many apps since I don't own an iPhone), but an example would be the iPhone shortcuts panels: you can hold on an app, and then drag it to another panel, sweeping while still dragging it. But this is the core app, is it possible to reproduce something similar within a normal app?

I only need to be sure it can be done before I start digging, I don't need code examples or anything, but if you have some exact resources that you consider helpful, that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you have your custom UIView subclass instance inside a UIScrollView, your view controller just needs to set the UIScrollView to delay content touches and not allow it to cancel touch events.

```
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
[scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
```

When the user taps and holds in the custom view, the event goes to that custom view, which can process the touch events to drag an item around, but if the user quickly swipes, it scrolls the view.

Answer (score 0):

The "panel" view that you're referring to appears to be a [`UIPageControl`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) view — although, perhaps, the specific incarnation of this view that Apple uses for the iPhone's home page may be customized.

Instances of generic `UIView` views that you might touch-and-drag will receive touch events. By overriding methods in the view, these events can be processed and passed to the page control, in order to tell it to "sweep" between pages.

If I wanted to do what you're asking about, that's how I might approach it. It seems doable to me, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this: [Swip from one view to the next view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993868/swip-from-one-view-to-the-next-view/1993883#1993883)

Try using a `UIButton` that tracks the time since the state of the button changed to "highlighted". You may need to do this in order to track the dragging and move the button around:

[Observing pinch multi-touch gestures in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003201/observing-pinch-multi-touch-gestures-in-a-uitableview/2003781#2003781)

Check to see if the button starts overlapping one side of the screen while being dragged. If s certain amount of time elapses since the button first started overlapping the edge and then manipulate the `UIScrollView` so that it switches to the next page on the corresponding side of the screen

You may need to use `NSTimer` to keep track of how long the button is held down, etc.

In any case there's no reason why this couldn't work.

If UIButton doesn't work then perhaps try a custom subclass of UIControl (which tracks the same touch down actions etc.). If that doesn't work then use the window event intercept thing to track everything.