# how to change uipagecontrol dots to number and space between each dots

Tags: ios, xcode, uipagecontrol

how  to change uipagecontrol dots to number and space between each dots.so it was very easy to initialize the page control events and also spaces for all dots.Now for me i using dots for changing page in uipagecontrol.

Answer (score 1):

`UIPageControl` class doesn't provide such functionality, it is very simple control. You have to create your own class to get the desired functionality. Refer to this question [Subclassing UIPageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020782/subclassing-uipagecontrol) for more information.

Comment: is possible to change number like 1 2 3 instead of dots.

Comment: no, you can always see what class provides by checking the DOCS http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Not really sure how else to say it. No, you can't set `UIPageControl` to use anything else but white dots. If you require anything else (such as numbers, different color for dots, etc.) You have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to generate your own buttons with page numbers which would work very similar to UIPageControl, see this tutorial for details:

http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.com/2013/05/uiscrollview-with-page-numbers-similar.html